# The Baer-Levi semigroup is right simple and right cancellative, but neither left simple nor left cancellative.

Tags: semigroups

This is Exercise 2.6.5(b) of Howie's *"Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory"*.

### The Details:

(Here I write maps on the right of their arguments, so $X\alpha$ means $\alpha(X)$.)

Let $S$ be a semigroup.

> **Definition 1:** Let $X$ be a countably infinite set and let $B$ be the set of one-to-one maps $\alpha: X\to X$ with the property that $X\setminus X\alpha$ is infinite. Then $B$ with composition is the *Baer-Levi semigroup*.
>
> **Definition 2:** We call $S$ *right simple* if $\mathcal R=S\times S$, and *left simple* if $\mathcal L=S\times S$, where $\mathcal R$ and $\mathcal L$ are Green's $R$- and $L$-relation, respectively.
>
> **Definition 3:** We call $S$ *right cancellative* if $(\forall a, b, c\in S) ac=bc\implies a=b$, and *left cancellative* if $(\forall a, b, c\in S) ca=cb\implies a=b$.

### The Question:

> Show that the Baer-Levi semigroup $B$ is right simple and right cancellative, but is neither left simple nor left cancellative.

### My Attempt:

I think it all follows from the maps being injective but working with the infinite set $X\setminus X\alpha$ for $\alpha\in B$  is tricky.